# mplayer does not recognize input.conf

Tags: keyboard, debian, media

I am trying to control mplayer 1.3.0 (Debian) with the mouse. After installing, the `input.conf` file at `~/.mplayer` was missing, so I created one. However, mplayer still does not react to the keybindings in this file.

I copied the keybindings to `/etc/mplayer/input.conf` and it worked, although not the mouse input. So I tried to reinstall mplayer by deleting the folders `~/.mplayer` and `/etc/mplayer` and running `sudo apt-get remove mplayer`

Now it is not even reacting to keybindings in `/etc/mplayer/input.conf` (which was an empty folder, I had to recreate this file) anymore.

How can I get mplayer to react to keyboard and/or mouse input again?? Thank you! :)

Edit: After further investigation, I suspect the problem has to do with the message "`Buffer is too small for command pause`" which I get after running mplayer. This is the only content of my `input.conf` files:

```
g pause
```

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt remove mplayer` only removes the program but not its configuration files to preserve them for a new installation. Try to use

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt purge mplayer
rpi ~$ sudo apt autoremove
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

That will also remove all configuration and maybe orphaned libraries. Then reboot and install mplayer again.